# js erb file in rails 3 for action in application controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app I just added a live search engine using:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

My implementation however, is in the header of the app, and therefore appears on all pages - with the results appearing in a sliding down div.

So my search controller is a search action in the application controller, and then added in the before filter in each sub controller.

In the railscast example, he has a js.erb file which is used to refresh the results while typing - I'm not sure where I should be putting this file or how I should setup the routes?

in my application_controller.rb:

```
  def search
      if params[:search]
        @results = Items.search(params[:search])
      end
  end
```

In my sub controllers:

```
before_filter :search
```

So where do I stick the js.erb file? and how should I create the routes around it?

Comment: Doesn't railscast cover this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick.

http://aymeric.gaurat.net/2010/how-to-develop-live-search-textbox-in-ruby-on-rails/